new `drive.meet.readonly` scope does not work with the drive.files.export method
I'm trying to switch from using the main https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly scope that allows access to the entire Drive to the new more restricted one https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.meet.readonly
Everything is doing fine during the metadata listing of the file:
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: googleAuth });

const metadataRes = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId,
    fields: "name",
  });

But when trying to get the content with the exact same file
   const contentRes = await drive.files.export({
      fileId: fileId,
      mimeType: "text/plain",
    });

Did anybody manage to get that new scope working when exporting the file content?
Looking at the doc, the drive.meet.readonly scope is supposed to give export access: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export
Or is it just buggy?

I understand, yeah I double checked the article and it seems that it is stating that let me remove my answer to avoid confusion

I tried to do a quick look up about this and it seems that there is nothing saying your article is deprecated, however during an error it seems that the article I included was the one being referred to as the better form of reference. With this I would suggest posting here at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues this way this can be raised to official Google Support.

Filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/365706547
